# Set path automatically after opening blender file

Tags: python, compositing-nodes, path

This script automatically add path to file ouput nodes in compositing.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Path Compositing",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 4, 0),
    "location": "Node Editor > Properties > Path",
    "description": "A tool to set the output path for all file output nodes in the compositing workspace",
    "category": "Compositing"
}

import bpy
import os

# New operator for updating the disk letter
class UpdateDiskLetterOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "path_setter.update_disk_letter"
    bl_label = "Update Disk Letter"
    bl_description = "Update the disk letter for all file output nodes in the compositing workspace"

    def execute(self, context):
        for node in bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == "OUTPUT_FILE":
                current_disk_letter = os.path.abspath(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath)[0]
                node_path_parts = os.path.splitdrive(node.base_path)
                new_path = os.path.join(current_disk_letter + ':', node_path_parts[1])
                node.base_path = new_path

        return {'FINISHED'}

class MainPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "main_panel"
    bl_label = "Path Setter"
    bl_space_type = "NODE_EDITOR"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Path"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "directory_level")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "render_folder_name")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "include_project_name", toggle=True, text="Include project name in path")
        if scene.include_project_name:
            row = layout.row()
            row.label(text="Current project name: " + bpy.path.display_name_from_filepath(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath))
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "node_label_suffix", text="Node label suffix")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("path_setter.set_path", text="Set Path")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("path_setter.clear_path", text="Clear Path")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("path_setter.update_disk_letter", text="Disk Letter")



class PathSetterOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "path_setter.set_path"
    bl_label = "Set Path"
    bl_description = "Set the output path for all file output nodes in the compositing workspace"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene

        # Get the output directory path
        directory = bpy.path.abspath("//")
        for i in range(scene.directory_level):
            directory = os.path.dirname(directory)
        directory = os.path.join(directory, scene.render_folder_name)

        if scene.include_project_name:
            # Add project folder to output path
            project_folder = bpy.path.display_name_from_filepath(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath)
            directory = os.path.join(directory, project_folder)

        # Set the path for all file output nodes
        for node in bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == "OUTPUT_FILE":
                node.base_path = os.path.join(directory, node.label + scene.node_label_suffix)

        return {'FINISHED'}


class ClearPathOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "path_setter.clear_path"
    bl_label = "Clear Path"
    bl_description = "Clear the output path for all file output nodes in the compositing workspace"

    def execute(self, context):
        for node in bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == "OUTPUT_FILE":
                node.base_path = ""

        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MainPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PathSetterOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ClearPathOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(UpdateDiskLetterOperator)
    bpy.types.Scene.directory_level = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Directory Level", default=3, min=0, max=10)
    bpy.types.Scene.render_folder_name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Render Folder Name", default="02-Render")
    bpy.types.Scene.include_project_name = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Include project name in path", default=True)
    bpy.types.Scene.node_label_suffix = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Node label suffix", default="")

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MainPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PathSetterOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ClearPathOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(UpdateDiskLetterOperator)
    del bpy.types.Scene.directory_level
    del bpy.types.Scene.render_folder_name
    del bpy.types.Scene.include_project_name
    del bpy.types.Scene.node_label_suffix


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

It's work fine but i can't start function from 'class PathSetterOperator' directly after opening blender file.

This is code with 'auto setup' function.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Path Compositing",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 4, 0),
    "location": "Node Editor > Properties > Path",
    "description": "A tool to set the output path for all file output nodes in the compositing workspace",
    "category": "Compositing",
}

import bpy
import os

# New operator for updating the disk letter
class UpdateDiskLetterOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "path_setter.update_disk_letter"
    bl_label = "Update Disk Letter"
    bl_description = "Update the disk letter for all file output nodes in the compositing workspace"

    def execute(self, context):
        for node in bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == "OUTPUT_FILE":
                current_disk_letter = os.path.abspath(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath)[0]
                node_path_parts = os.path.splitdrive(node.base_path)
                new_path = os.path.join(current_disk_letter + ':', node_path_parts[1])
                node.base_path = new_path

        return {'FINISHED'}

class MainPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "main_panel"
    bl_label = "Path Setter"
    bl_space_type = "NODE_EDITOR"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Path"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "directory_level")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "render_folder_name")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "include_project_name", toggle=True, text="Include project name in path")
        if scene.include_project_name:
            row = layout.row()
            row.label(text="Current project name: " + bpy.path.display_name_from_filepath(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath))
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "node_label_suffix", text="Node label suffix")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("path_setter.set_path", text="Set Path")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("path_setter.clear_path", text="Clear Path")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("path_setter.update_disk_letter", text="Update Disk Letter")

        # Add a checkbox to enable/disable "Set Path on Startup" function
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "enable_set_path_on_startup", text="Enable Set Path on Startup")

class PathSetterOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "path_setter.set_path"
    bl_label = "Set Path"
    bl_description = "Set the output path for all file output nodes in the compositing workspace"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene

        # Get the output directory path
        blend_file_directory = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
        parent_directory = os.path.dirname(blend_file_directory)
        grandparent_directory = os.path.dirname(parent_directory)

        render_folder_name = ""
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(grandparent_directory):
            for dir in dirs:
                if "render" in dir.lower():
                    render_folder_name = dir
                    break
            if render_folder_name:
                break

        if not render_folder_name:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "No 'render' folder found two directories above the Blender file.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        # Construct the output path
        directory = os.path.join(grandparent_directory, render_folder_name)

        if scene.include_project_name:
            # Add project folder to output path
            project_folder = bpy.path.display_name_from_filepath(bpy.data.filepath)
            directory = os.path.join(directory, project_folder)

        # Set the path for all file output nodes
        for node in bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == "OUTPUT_FILE":
                node.base_path = os.path.join(directory, node.label + scene.node_label_suffix)

        return {'FINISHED'}

class ClearPathOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "path_setter.clear_path"
    bl_label = "Clear Path"
    bl_description = "Clear the output path for all file output nodes in the compositing workspace"

    def execute(self, context):
        for node in bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == "OUTPUT_FILE":
                node.base_path = ""

        return {'FINISHED'}

class SetPathOnStartupOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "path_setter.set_path_on_startup"
    bl_label = "Set Path on Startup"
    bl_description = "Set the output path for all file output nodes when opening a Blender file"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.path_setter.set_path()
        return {'FINISHED'}

def toggle_set_path_on_startup(self, context):
    if context.scene.enable_set_path_on_startup:
        bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(set_path_on_startup_handler)
    else:
        bpy.app.handlers.load_post.remove(set_path_on_startup_handler)

def set_path_on_startup_handler(dummy):
    bpy.ops.path_setter.set_path()

# Add a Boolean property to enable/disable "Set Path on Startup" function
bpy.types.Scene.enable_set_path_on_startup = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
    name="Enable Set Path on Startup",
    default=False,
    update=toggle_set_path_on_startup
)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MainPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PathSetterOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ClearPathOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(UpdateDiskLetterOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SetPathOnStartupOperator)
    bpy.types.Scene.directory_level = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Directory Level", default=3, min=0, max=10)
    bpy.types.Scene.render_folder_name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Render Folder Name", default="02-Render")
    bpy.types.Scene.include_project_name = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Include project name in path", default=True)
    bpy.types.Scene.node_label_suffix = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Node label suffix", default="")

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MainPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PathSetterOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ClearPathOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UpdateDiskLetterOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SetPathOnStartupOperator)
    del bpy.types.Scene.directory_level
    del bpy.types.Scene.render_folder_name
    del bpy.types.Scene.include_project_name
    del bpy.types.Scene.node_label_suffix
    del bpy.types.Scene.enable_set_path_on_startup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Please help me to make 'class SetPathOnStartupOperator' in the second code workable.